# Inheritance of private variables

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find a definite answer to my question. Say we had the two following classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int gasTank;
    private int milesDriven;

    void Vehicle(int gas, int milesDriven) {
        gasTank = gas;
        this.milesDriven = milesDriven;
    }

    void move(int miles) {
        gasTank -= subclass.getMileage() * miles;  // I know this doesn't work but bear with me
        milesDriven += miles;
    }
}

public class HyundaiSonata extends Vehicle {
    private int mileage;

    void HyundaiSonata () { super(40, 5000); }

    int getMileage() {return mileage;}
}
```

Essentially, my question is on line 11. There is no way to access subclass methods or fields, as inheritance only flows up, so how would I structure this otherwise?

Edit: Please note that the solution should work for the general case where I have hundreds of different vehicles extending the Vehicle class

Comment: Your `move` method should work for any instance of `Vehicle`, which implies every `Vehicle` must support the `getMileage()` method. This suggests you should move that method to the base class.

Comment: A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class.

Comment: That is incorrect Rcordoval. Subclass does inherit, except it is hidden.

Comment: But the getMileage method should return a different value depending on what the mileage of the exact vehicle is. How would I access that value if it is in the subclass?

Comment: Make `getMileage()` method abstract, to ensure that it will be overridden by non-abstract subclasses. Then you can use `getMileage()` in `move` method, even if it is not implemented yet (its code will be dynamically binded from actual object's class).

Comment: subclass does not inherit private fields, but you can have public or protected methods which subclass can use to access to access the private fields.

Comment: @Pshemo I tried that method as well. However, in my actual project, I have multiple methods that, like the move method, has shared behaviour between the subclasses. So I'd have to basically override every getter and setter method for every field that I have. And frankly, it's easier to just override the move method if it comes to that

Comment: @BhavyaBansal What if I were to make a new protected field called mileage. Would every instance of a subclass have its own copy of that field, or simply a reference to the same one

Comment: @BhavyaBansal because then I could in theory instantiate every object with its own mileage in its constructor and assign it to the superclass protected field, if that makes any sense whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override you move method in the child class. Make your move method abstract in the parent class.

One way i can argue about this is let the Vehicle class have many child class ,in that case it would be not possible for you to write your move method in the Vehicle class, as you could not know which sub class mileage to refer.

So here is the corrected code.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int gasTank;
    private int milesDriven;

    void Vehicle(int gas, int milesDriven) {
        gasTank = gas;
        this.milesDriven = milesDriven;
    }
    // make this function abstract
    abstract void move(int miles); 

}

public class Hyundai Sonata extends Vehicle {
    private int mileage;

    void Hyundai Sonata () { super(40, 5000); }

    void getMileage() {return mileage;}
    //override it here
    @Override
    public void move(int miles){
    gasTank -=this.getMileage() * miles;
        milesDriven += miles; 
    }

}
```

Edit 1:-

As pointed by you in the comment here is a way to solve it.

Make you mileage variable a entity of vehicle class.

So your vehicle class will look like

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int gasTank;
    private int milesDriven;
    private int mileage;
    void Vehicle(int gas, int milesDriven,int mileage) {
        gasTank = gas;
        this.milesDriven = milesDriven;
        this.mileage=mileage;
    }
    public void move(int miles){
     gasTank -=mileage * miles;
    milesDriven += miles; 
}


}
```

And your sub class will look like.

```
 public class Hyundai Sonata extends Vehicle {
        private int mileage;

        void Hyundai Sonata () { super(40, 5000,mileage); }



        }

}
```

Comment: fan-Shashank this was my original solution. However, I am simply copying pasting my code quite a bit, which OOP is supposed to help avoid. If I had something closer to 100 subclasses, how could I avoid overriding every move method?

Comment: this is what I tried to do. But for some reason, whenever I do something like:
Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[]{new Hyundai_Sonata, new Ford_Truck};
     for (Vehicle next : vehicles)
         next.move(20);

Then what ends up happening is that the milesDriven gets updated to 5020, but then when the ford_truck gets moved, the milesDriven gets updated to 5040, if that makes any sense. It's like there's only 1 copy of milesDriven

Comment: @stackUnderflow i could not understand what you want to say. Please ellaborate

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter I'm editing right now

Comment: Essentially, for some reason, I only have one copy of milesDriven. I have triple-checked, and the obvious answer that I made my milesDriven variable static is not true. It's not static and is protected, and yet every time I update milesDriven, it is cumulative for some reason

Comment: Nevermind I believe I have found out the bug. It was unrelated to my problem. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
protected abstract int getMileage();
```

In super class and subclass needs to override it

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int gasTank;
    private int milesDriven;

    void Vehicle(int gas, int milesDriven) {
        gasTank = gas;
        this.milesDriven = milesDriven;
    }

    protected abstract int getMileage(); // Introduce this abstract method

    void move(int miles) {
        gasTank -= subclass.getMileage() * miles;  
        milesDriven += miles;
    }
}

public class HyundaiSonata extends Vehicle {
    private int mileage;

    void HyundaiSonata () { super(40, 5000); }

    @Override 
    public int getMileage() {return mileage;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the subclasses to implement the `getMileage` method by making it `abstract`. In this way the subclasses need to implement only the behaviour that is unknown to the `Vehicle` class, unaware/decoupled from the logic of the `move` method. That should look something like this.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int gasTank;
    private int milesDriven;

    Vehicle(int gas, int milesDriven) {
        gasTank = gas;
        this.milesDriven = milesDriven;
    }

    void move(int miles) {
        gasTank -= this.getMileage() * miles;
        milesDriven += miles;
    }

    abstract int getMileage()
}

public class HyundaiSonata extends Vehicle {
    HyundaiSonata () { super(40, 5000); }

    @Override
    int getMileage() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```